# Как ускорить загрузку писем в roundcube

Tags: exim, dovecot, roundcube

я использую ISPManager с установленными из коробки exim, dovecot, roundcube
Столкнулся с проблемой долгой загрузки страницы с письмами, сейчас около 5 миллиона писем

При открытии например папки Входящие, она открывается около 5 секунд
Если сделать поиск по всем папкам, то он занимает более 2 минут

Как можно ускорить работу?

Может возможно хранить все письма dovecot в БД(mysql, postgresql), но не нашел статей, везде способ хранения это файлы

Попробовал несколько десктопных почтовых клиентов, папки открываются быстро и поиск работает быстро, как я понял при открытии клиента происходит сканирование всех писем с сервера и сохранение в свою БД,  при открытии папки, письма загружаются из их БД
Может возможно настроить roundcube, что бы он хранил письма у себя в БД и открывал их из свое БД, а не из файлов doveco?

Параметры сервера
Процессор: 8 ядер AMD Ryzon 9 (Нагрузка не более 20%)
Оперативная память: 16 gb (Нагрузка не более 20%)
NVMe: 1000 gb (Нагрузка не более 60%)